# Is it normal/acceptable for an ROC curve to have values that cross the 1-to-1 ratio line?

Tags: python, plot, roc

I'm plotting a Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) Curve, but some of the values go over the 1-to-1 ratio line. I thought that this was impossible, but I'm unsure now because I believe my code is correct.

I've plotted the ROC curve and have completed the code.

```
def perf_measure(exval, thval):
    y_true = [0] * len(thval)
    y_pred = [0] * len(thval)

    for i in range(len(thval)): 
        if abs(exval[i] - thval[i]) <= 0.5:
           y_true[i] = 1
           y_pred[i] = 0
        elif abs(exval[i] - thval[i]) > 0.5:
           y_true[i] = 0
           y_pred[i] = 1

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np.array(thval), np.array(y_pred), test_size=0.5, random_state=1)

    X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape((len(X_train), 1))
    X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape((len(X_test), 1))
    lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    y_train = lab_enc.fit_transform(np.array(y_train).astype('int'))
    logmodel = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='auto')
    logmodel.fit(X_train, y_train)
    probs = logmodel.predict_proba(X_test)
    preds = probs[:,1]

    fpr, tpr, th = roc_curve(y_test, preds)
    auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, preds)
    auc = round(auc, 2)

    return(fpr, tpr, auc)
```

The code should be outputting the ROC correctly, unless I messed something up? exval is the accepted values. thval is the theoretical values. Both are inputted as a list of size 1-by-len(thval).

The main thing I would like to know is if the plot looks acceptable. If not, is something wrong with my code?

Comment: First question so don't have the reputation. Here's the pic:
[ROC curve](https://i.imgur.com/mW5A6Cd.png)

Comment: Not impossible, but every example I can find of a ROC curve only has values above this line.

Comment: That's because people don't want to show you the others, not because they don't exist.